# Can cURL block a rogue CA?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, curl

I know which Certificate Authority (CA) my server uses for its TLS certs.

My client system also knows who the CA is.

When I use cURL, I can specify `--cacert` to specify a custom CA file to use, but it seems that this is used IN ADDITION to the trusted CAs installed on my system, not *instead of*.

So is there a way of telling cURL to **ONLY** accept CA certs that I know to expect, when making a connection to my server?

Otherwise, I can't detect a rogue CA from issuing a cert for my server unless I manually scrape the verbose connection details during connection...

Answer (score 1):

Good question - in a browser there is certificate pinning.
After looking this up I came across the curl flag `--pinnedpubkey`

> **Certificate pinning**
>
> TLS certificate pinning is a way to verify that the public key used to
>   sign the servers certificate has not changed. It is "pinned".
>
> When negotiating a TLS or SSL connection, the server sends a
>   certificate indicating its identity. A public key is extracted from
>   this certificate and if it does not exactly match the public key
>   provided to this option, curl will abort the connection before sending
>   or receiving any data.
>
> You tell curl a file name to read the sha256 value from, or you
>   specify the base64 encoded hash directly in the command line with a
>   sha256// prefix. You can specify one or more hashes like that,
>   separated with semicolons (;).
>
> curl --pinnedpubkey "sha256//83d34tasd3rt..." https://example.com/
>   This feature is not supported by all TLS backends.

Reference:
https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-tls.html

Comment: It's a good answer, but doesn't work for me - I know the root CA for the server issuing my certs, but I have no visibility of the certs themselves, so am unable to use this option.

Comment: You can find the pubkey of the server as visible to your box via `curl -v https://host --pinnedpubkey sha256//` and it will be above the failure message: but of course the only way to know it is correct for sure is to calculate it from the server certificate or trust the CA chain

Answer (score 0):

At least on "Debianic" Linux systems, *curl* uses `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` as default for `--cacert` and `/etc/ssl/certs` as default for `--capath`.

You may set `--cacert` and `--capath` explicitly to "overwrite" these defaults. Note that you have to set both; otherwise the default is used for the non-given option.

Example:

```
curl --cacert my_certs_file --capath my_certs_dir ...
```

`my_certs_file` contains your custom CA file; `my_certs_dir` is a directory that is empty here.

It is also possible to store your custom CA file(s) in `my_certs_dir` (do not forget to execute `c_rehash my_certs_dir` after storing). The file `my_certs_file` may not be left empty (depends on *curl* version), but must contain at least one syntactically correct certificate.

(What a coincidence: Today I walked into the "default" trap, too--and found the described solution.)